# REGEX - php preg_replace :

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to replace part of a string based on a "." (period) character 
only if it appears after/before/between a word(s),
not when it is before/between any number(s).

Example:

```
This is a text string.
```

-Should be able to replace the `"string."` with `"string ."`
 (note the Space between the end of the word and the period)

Example 2

```
This is another text string. 2.0 times longer.
```

-Should be able to replace `"string."` with `"string ."`
 (note the Space between the end of the word and the period)
-Should Not replace `"2.0"` with `"2 . 0"`

It should only do the replacement if the "." appears at the end/start of a word.

Yes - I've tried various bits of regex.
But everything I do results in either nothing happening,
or the numbers are fine, but I take the last letter from the word preceeding the "."
(thus instead of "string." I end up with "strin g.")

Yes - I've looked through numerous posts here - I have seen Nothing that deals with the desire, nor the "strange" problem of grabbing the char before the ".".

Comment: `only if it appears after/before/between a word(s), not when it is before/between a word(s)`:  Don't those two conditions contradict each other?

Comment: @mellamokb - apologies, you are correct.  It should be "numbers" for the second part.  Updated with correction.

Comment: $text = preg_replace('/(\b[^\d]+\b)(\.{1})/', ' $1 $2 ', $text);  //// That seems to work (I did some whilst waiting for responses).  The question is - is it worse/better/equal that some of the stuff presented?

Comment: Correction ... $text = preg_replace('/(\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)(\.{1})/', ' $1 $2 ', $text);  ... appears to work.

Comment: `/(\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)(\.{1})/` won't match `.and`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lookbehind `(?<=REXP)`

```
preg_replace("/(?<=[a-z])\./i", "XXX", "2.0 test. abc")    // <- "2.0 testXXX abc"
```

which will only match if the text before matches the corresponding regex (in this case `[a-z]`). You may use a lookahead `(?=REXP)` in the same way to test text after the match.

Note: There is also a negative lookbehind `(?<!REXP)` and a negative lookahead `(?!REXP)` available which will reject matches if the `REXP` does not match before or after.

Comment: lookbehind ?!? Did not know that, it looks awesome! +1

Comment: Wow - not only cool, but explains the LB/LA as well (in a way that made sense to me :D)

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = "This is another text string. 2.0 times longer.";
echo preg_replace("/(^\.|\s\.|\.\s|\.$)/", " $1", $input);
```

http://ideone.com/xJQzQ

Comment: I cannot gaurante spaces being anywhere specific - I may get a string of "this and that.that and this.this 2.34 then that 78.01."

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific then as to what a word is defined as, since "2.0" and "google.com" and "Mrs. Smith" and "M.L.K." all look the same to a simple definition.

Comment: Very good point!  I will ahve to check for following chars :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too good with the regex, but this is what I would do to accomplish the task with basic PHP. Basically explode the entire string by it's . values, look at each variable to see if the last character is a letter or number and add a space if it's a number, then puts the variable back together.

```
<?
$string = "This is another text string. 2.0 times longer.";
print("$string<br>");
$string = explode(".",$string);
$stringcount = count($string);
for($i=0;$i<$stringcount;$i++){
    if(is_numeric(substr($string[$i],-1))){
        $string[$i] = $string[$i] . " ";
    }
}
$newstring = implode('.',$string);
print("$newstring<br>");
?>
```

Comment: That looks heavily complicated ... I was hoping for a "simple" regex - but thank you none the less :D

Comment: I just realized it was backwards, putting the space where there is numeric, you'd just have to change the code to say if it wasn't numeric, insert the space. All this is doing, is what the regex others have posted, but without regex.

Answer (score 0):

`It should only do the replacement if the "." appears at the end/start of a word.`

search: `/([a-z](?=\.)|\.(?=[a-z]))/`
replace: `"$1 "`
modifiers: `ig` (case insensitive, globally)

Test in Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $samp = '
This is another text string. 2.0 times longer.
I may get a string of "this and that.that and this.this 2.34 then that 78.01."
';

$samp =~ s/([a-z](?=\.)|\.(?=[a-z]))/$1 /ig;

print "$samp";
```

Input:
`This is another text string. 2.0 times longer.`
`I may get a string of "this and that.that and this.this 2.34 then that 78.01."`

Output:
`This is another text string . 2.0 times longer .`
`I may get a string of "this and that . that and this . this 2.34 then that 78.01."`

Comment: It's jsut that adding the /g seems to cause a problem? (Unless I'm doing it wrong?)

Comment: Here is a list of possible modifiers in php: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php. You don't use 'g' modifier in preg_replace(), it is the default. You can set a limit though. Here is an example: http://www.ideone.com/1L9Mp